# GridFS file retrieval strategy

Tags: mongodb, cpu-usage, gridfs, fetching-strategy

I have been looking at GridFS to store images and other files.

It has some really nice features but we have to retrieve and store files at some temporary location to render html which costs us cpu time.

What would be a good strategy to use GridFS and minimize this cost?

Comment: Why are you storing the files in some temporary location?

Comment: we do it to provide src/href to img/a elements.

Comment: can't you just stream the data directly from GridFS on whatever platform you're using? You shouldn't need an intermediate storage.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb supports REST. So you don't have to download file to a temporary storage. With rest, you just need to append the REST link of the file to your html.

[See mongodb simple rest interface here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-interface)