# MongoDB GridFS Clarification

Tags: mongodb, image-processing, mongoose, database

I deployed the mongodb gridfs for reduce the image rendering time and reduce the apache request. I need some clarification regarding large size of image how we can show it in browser?.

Actually i taken single image and size more than 40MB for store it in mongodb gridfs. Its stored by using following command. But ***i cant able to show it in browser 40MB image in browser and how we can stream the image in browser?***. Pls help us.

Commands:

***Step 1:***

```
./mongofiles -d myfiles put /home/bharat/bin/cron/"CT0072 Madagascar Cartoon Characters .jpg"
connected to: 127.0.0.1
added file: { _id: ObjectId('512606b93f15f684e8271aee'), filename: "/home/bharat/bin/cron/CT0072 Madagascar Cartoon Characters .jpg", chunkSize: 262144, uploadDate: new Date(1361446588575), md5: "ab3e9d6a6f01f87e28f76148824a6d4b", length: 20020718 }
done!
```

***Step 2:***

```
./mongofiles -d myfiles list
connected to: 127.0.0.1
/home/bharat/bin/cron/CT0072 Madagascar Cartoon Characters .jpg 20020718
```

***Step 3:***

```
./mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.8.2
> show tables;
fs.chunks
fs.files
system.indexes
> db.fs.chunks.count();
77
```

***Step 4:*** 
Write PHP File

```
**Program 1** - Its showing image below 10MB file. But 40MB file is not showing in Chrome Browse but Firefox showing and taking more time to display.

$mongo = new Mongo("128.181.10.28:27017");
$db = $mongo->myfiles;
$gridFS = $db->getGridFS();
$image = $gridFS->findOne("/home/bharat/bin/cron/tomas-hurricane.jpg");
$filedata = $image->getBytes();
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($filedata));
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
ob_clean();
echo($filedata);

**Program 2** : Tried second program but not working.

Tried 2nd Program
$mongo = new Mongo("128.181.10.28:27017");
$db = $mongo->myfiles;
$gridFS = $db->getGridFS();
$image = $gridFS->findOne("/home/bharat/bin/cron/tomas-hurricane.jpg");
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$stream = $image->getResource();
while (!feof($stream)) {
    echo fread($stream, 8192);
}
```

- Kumaran

Comment: How long does it take to read all of the bytes from your MongoDB server in the second case?

Comment: Program 2 : in FireFox : taken 20Sec but its not working in Chrome browser its showing only blank white page.

Comment: Can Chrome show the file OK if you just locally load it into Chrome (not via MongoDB?) Also -- Can you also send the `content-length`?

Comment: I think this is more related to the client side displaying these humongous images. How long does it take to open them locally, with your browser? If it takes the same time, then this is not a mongo issue...

Answer (score 0):

First, 40 MB is really big to show for a browser, especially if you are using IE. Try smaller images.

And second, as I have pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396398/gridfs-file-retrieval-strategy/14805845#14805845), you can use MongoDB REST API which is a great way to get images.